# First 8 videos (out of 32) rendering twice from Firebase database in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my custom hook which is fetching videos from Firebase realtime database:

```
import {
  get,
  getDatabase,
  limitToFirst,
  orderByKey,
  query,
  ref,
  startAt,
} from "firebase/database";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useVideoList(page) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchVideos() {
      //database related works
      const db = getDatabase();
      const videosRef = ref(db, "videos");
      const videoQuery = query(
        videosRef,
        orderByKey(),
        startAt("" + page),
        limitToFirst(8)
      );

      try {
        setError(false);
        setLoading(true);
        //request firebase database

        const snapshot = await get(videoQuery);
        setLoading(false);

        if (snapshot.exists()) {
          setVideos((prevVideos) => {
            return [...prevVideos, ...Object.values(snapshot.val())];
          });
        } else {
          setHasMore(false);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
        setError(true);
      }
    }

    fetchVideos();
  }, [page]);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    videos,
    hasMore,
  };
}
```

This is a part my Videos component which is rendering videos from the hook:

```
          {videos.map((video) =>
            video.noq > 0 ? (
              <Link key={video.youtubeID} to="/quiz">
                <Video
                  title={video.title}
                  id={video.youtubeID}
                  noq={video.noq}
                />
              </Link>
            ) : (
              <Video
                key={video.youtubeID}
                title={video.title}
                id={video.youtubeID}
                noq={video.noq}
              />
            )
          )}
```

I am trying to bring only 32 videos. But I am getting 40 videos( first 8 are rendering twice).I tried several methods, searched google...couldn't find an answer.